# How to fetch id of selected chebox and export selected record as CSV using Codeigniter()?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am not able to get how I can fetch the ids to export the records.

I have a dropdown button which contains three options (import, export and create new user). Once I click on the export button, the records where the checkbox is selected should be exported as a CSV file.

How the button looks like:

[image]

I have code for exporting a CSV file, but I am not able to fetch the ids of the checkboxes.

Export CSV file code (working fine):

```
public function export_csv($param = '')
{
    $filename = strtotime("now"). ".csv"; 
    $delimiter = ","; 

    // Create a file pointer 
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 

    // Set column headers 
    $fields = array('Id', 'Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Created', 'Status'); 
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter); 

    $lineData = array(1,'34',$param,'859685968','29-09-2019','online');
    fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter); 

    // Move back to beginning of file 
    fseek($f, 0); 
    ob_clean();
    // Set headers to download file rather than displayed 
    header('Content-Type: text/csv'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";'); 

    // Output all remaining data on a file pointer 
    fpassthru($f); 

    // Exit from file 
    exit();
}
```

HTML table will be looking like:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 2%;"><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_check" class="checkbox select_check" ></th>
            <th style="width: 18%;">الاسم</th>
            <th style="width: 5%;"></th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">البريد الالكتروني</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">مدينة</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">اخر ظهور</th>
            <th style="width: 50%;">زيارات الموقع</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if (count($all_visitors) > 0): ?>
            <?php foreach($all_visitors as $visitor) : ?>
                <form method="POST">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="select_checkbox[]" id="select_checkbox" class="checkbox selectall_checkbox" value="<?=$visitor['id']?>"></td>
                    <td><?= !empty($visitor['full_name']) ? $visitor['full_name'] : 'الاسم لم يعطى حتى الان'?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?= BASE_URL.'chats?id='.$visitor['unique_id']?>" style="<?= empty($visitor["chat_id"]) ? " pointer-events: none;cursor: default;" :''?>"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </td>
                    <td><?= !empty($visitor['email']) ? $visitor['email'] : 'البريد الإلكتروني لم يعطى حتى الان'?></td>
                    <td><?= !empty($visitor['city']) ? $visitor['city'] : 'لم يتم إعطاء المدينة بعد'?></td>
                    <td><?= !empty($visitor['updated']) ? get_timeago(strtotime($visitor['updated'])) : '30 Seconds ago'?></td>
                    <td class="site-visits" ><?= !empty($visitor['total_visits']) ? $visitor['total_visits'] : '0'?></td>
                </tr>
                </form>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <tr><td colspan="6">No records found</td></tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you post data to your controller method,

access them like below

```
$ids=$this->input->post('select_checkbox');
```

If you do, `print_r($ids)`, you will have values like below for example

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

Then, make create query and export to csv, codeigniter `dbutil` has easy way to transform your query to csv,  below is snippet to do that,

```
public function export_csv()
{

      /* Usually ids will be integers, so lets just filter only integer ids 
         from user input, 
        1st RULE : Never Trust User Inputs
        2nd RULE : always validate User Inputs
      */
      $ids =  array_filter( $this->input->post('select_checkbox'), 'is_int');

      if($ids)
      {

         $this->load->dbutil();
         $this->load->helper('file');
         $this->load->helper('download');

         $query = $this->db->select('Id', 'Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Created', 'Status')
                           ->where_in('Id', $ids)
                           ->get("your_table");


         $delimiter = ",";
         $newline = "\r\n";
         $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline);

         /* output to browser */
         force_download('Somereport.csv', $data);
     }

}
```

if you prefer to download on click of somebutton, then your JQuery snippet would be,

```
$(function(){

          /* Easy way is to set 
             action="http://example.com/your_controller/export_csv"
             in your export form and then submit
          */

         $('#your_export_button_outside_form').on("click",function()
         {
           /*
            $('#your_export_form').attr('action','http://example.com/your_controller/export_csv');
            */

            $('#your_export_form').submit();

         });
})
```

Comment: My button is outside the table. How can i manage the same? How I can get the post value.

Comment: I also try with the ajax but it simply prints the data, not download the content